# Не удается запустить приложение Flutter в Windows

Tags: flutter

Не могу запустить Flutter app на Windows
error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(240,5): error MSB8066: пользовательская сборка для "C:\Users\koval\Google Drive\usu\build\windows\CMakeFiles\001f907f757f26e1d0e8ea253f012e02\flutter_windows.dll.rule;C:\Users\koval\Google Drive\usu\build\windows\CMakeFiles\3fd8b3cb8a370a7ca36fab97595ceccb\flutter_assemble.rule" завершила работу с кодом 1. [C:\Users\koval\Google Drive\usu\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
Exception: Build process failed.
```

В чем проблема?

beta channel

Comment: Можно же нормально логи прикрепить?) А не одной строкой)

Comment: Где логи сборки? `flutter run --verbose`

Comment: @MiT Когда выполнил - flutter run --verbose то прога запустилась. У меня такая ошибка вылетает когда я запускаю сочетанием клавиш `shift+F10`

Comment: @Jedy значит у вас Visual Studio не настроен на запуск flutter

Comment: @MiT Так я запускаю в Android Studio

Comment: @Jedy `Google Drive` попробуйте сделать путь до проекта без пробелов.

Comment: @MiT Спасибо сработало, дуже не думал что из-за такое мелочи может быть такая проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Перенос ответа из комментариев, чтобы закрыть вопрос.*

Issue: [[windows][proposal] pre-check the path for spaces before building and provide an error message instead of trying to build](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75611)

Проблема связанная в пути до исполняемого файла. Если в нем есть пробел, cmake падает с ошибкой. При запуске из команды `flutter run`, ошибки нет.

Пример:

```
C:\Users\koval\Google Drive\usu\build\windows\CMakeFiles\...
```

Пробел в `Google Drive`, вызывает ошибку.